422 response to POST login data aft
I deployed my MERN app on vercel, but i can't login into the web app i build, i keep getting 422 (Unprocessable Content) and the error message was "please fill in all fields", even though i already filled all fields.
this is my codes on userController.js
// =====================LOGIN A REGISTERED USER
// POST : api/users/login
// UNPROTECTED
const loginUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return next(new HttpError("Please fill in all fields", 422));
    }
    const newEmail = email.toLowerCase();

    const user = await User.findOne({ email: newEmail });

    if (!user) {
      return next(new HttpError("Invalid credentials", 422));
    }

    const comparePassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!comparePassword) {
      return next(new HttpError("Invalid credentials", 422));
    }

    const { _id: id, name } = user;
    const token = jwt.sign({ id, name }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "1d",
    });

    res.status(200).json({ token, id, name });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new HttpError("User login failed", 422));
  }
};

and this is my codes for fetching data from users api
  const loginUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/users/login`,
        userData
      );
      const user = await response.data;
      setCurrentUser(user);
      console.log(user);
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response?.data);
      setError(error.response?.data?.message);
    }
  };

i checked on postman and everything went well, then i checked the website api deployment on vercel (https://my-application-name.vercel.app/api/users/login), it said ->
This Serverless Function has timed out.
Your connection is working correctly.
Vercel is working correctly.
504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT
ID: sin1::scx92-1719226958391-8ad636fa963b
